# is using map instead of a for loop a bad idea in JS?

Tags: javascript

**given an array of objects**

```
l = [a,b,c,d]

l.map(function(x){x.zop({foo:bar})})
```

is this a bad idea?

i mean it works and all :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to use array iteration functions and I personaly try to use them whenever I can instead of a for loop. The main reasons I do so are:

- No need to declare useless variables (like the loop counter) that clutter the code and confuse my JSHint.
- I need to write down the array only once. This makes it easier to rename the array variable if I want to and it is also more amenable to passing an expression directly (instead of having to save the array in aother extraneous variable)
- Regular for loops are vulnerable to the closures-inside-for-loops bug.

Do remember though that `map`, `forEach` and friends are not present in older browsers (particularly, Internet Explorer) so you should either use a shim (to add these methods to the native arrays) or use similar functions from a custom library.

edit: nowadays you should feel free to use these functions. If you still need to support IE8 you have bigger problems than this...

Comment: Addendum: `map` is an overkill for the task of iteration, since it returns an array of returned values. Besides, you can't break the loop with `map` (or `forEach`). What might replace the general for-loop is [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which breaks the loop if you return `false` in the iterator.

Comment: @katspaugh: Its even worse then that if you are wiling to look into this direction. Regular for loops can freely use `break`, `continue` and `return` for control flow and you can also rewind through multiple levels (with return or labeled breaks). That said, the vast majority of the time you just want a plain foreach and in that case not being able to break the loop might even be considered a feature. And we better not get started on `this` not having lexical scope.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery, this isn't a bad idea at all, but the standard pattern is to use `.each()`:

```
var $l = $(selector);
$l.each(function(){ $(this).css({foo:bar}) });
```

The main difference is that `.map()` is intended to return an array of modified objects, whereas `.each()` just runs a function on each object - so it's conceptually closer to what you're trying to do, and probably more efficient (because it doesn't need to create the return array).

This assumes that your "array of jQuery objects" is in fact a jQuery object itself (that would be the standard approach). If not, you can use `.forEach()` instead - this is the standard Array method.

If you're just talking generally about arrays, there are a couple of points to consider:

- As others have noted, older browsers don't support `.map()` and `.forEach()` natively, so you'd need some kind of shim or polyfill if you're looking to support those environments.
- One good thing about `.map()` and `.forEach()`, however, and one of the reasons I use them more often than `for` loops, is that they give you a new function scope within the loop. This means that you can create closures within the loop that reference the current item, which is a total pain with a `for` loop. For example:

  ```
  list.forEach(function($item) {
      $item.click(function() {
          alert("This is item " + $item.data('name'))
      })
  });
  ```

  (This is a bit of a red herring with jQuery, because you can use `$(this)`, but there are lots of places where it's quite useful.)
- Using `.map()` and `.forEach()` allows you to reuse the function if you like, in a way that's possible but less elegant in a `for` loop:

  ```
  function foo($item) { $item.css({foo:"bar"}) }
  list.forEach(foo);
  anotherList.forEach(foo);
  ```
- This is just personal preference, but I find the syntax and style more elegant in general than a `for` loop, and you avoid putting an iteration variable like `x` in the current scope.
- When you're dealing with nested structures, you get to give each level a descriptive name if you use `.map()` and `.forEach()`, which makes your code more legible. For example:

  ```
  states.forEach(function(state) {
      state.forEach(function(county) {
          county.forEach(function(city) {
              alert(city + ', ' + county + ', ' + state);
          })
      });
  });
  ```

  Compare to nested `for` loops, where your inner `alert` statement would look something like:

  ```
  alert(cities[x] + ', ' + cities[x][y] + ', ' + cities[x][y][z]);
  ```

Comment: word.. i guess it was a more general question :D

Comment: See some more general answers. :)

Comment: i love this answer so much :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to support old browsers without using shims, it's a bad idea.

If you don't mind dropping support for old browsers or loading shims to make them make them work, it's fine.

On the other hand, [some](http://twitter.com/#!/Cinsoft) argue that using shims is a bad idea.  If that's the case, and you need to support old browsers, then `map` is a bad idea. Personally, I'm still on the fence about the shim issue.

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but be aware that jQuery's `map` will flatten arrays, which is not what `map` functions normally do, so some folks consider that implementation to be broken.

---

Just for fun, here are some counterarguments to [missingno's arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338627/886931) for iteration functions.

> No need to declare useless variables (like the loop counter)

Loops don't always have to have counters. When you're dealing with disposable arrays of objects, for example, loops like this work nicely:

```
var things = [{foo:1}, {bar:2}, {foo:3}, {bar:4}], item;
while (item = things.shift()) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

> In a regular for loop I have to type the array name multiple times (so its more work if I want to rename it)

In the example above, we only had to type the array name once after it was declared. Even with a non-disposable array, where we'd need a counter for our loop, we still wouldn't need to type the name of the array any extra times.

> Regular for loops are vulnerable to the closures-inside-for-loops bug.

Yeah, you got me there :)